# ImportError: No module named oslo_config.cfg - Ryu App

Tags: python, sdn, ryu

I am running a sample Ryu application as outlined here: https://ryu-zhdoc.readthedocs.org/en/latest/writing_ryu_app.html

But I am getting the following error:

```
     Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/ryu-manager", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('ryu==3.29.1', 'console_scripts', 'ryu-manager')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 351, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2363, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2088, in load
    entry = __import__(self.module_name, globals(),globals(), ['__name__'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ryu/cmd/manager.py", line 31, in <module>
    from ryu import cfg
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ryu/cfg.py", line 17, in <module>
    import oslo_config.cfg
ImportError: No module named oslo_config.cfg
```

I have already tried the following commands and none have resolved my issue yet:

```
sudo pip install oslo.config
sudo apt-get upgrade python-oslo.config
sudo apt-get install python-oslo python-netaddr
```

I am just beginning to familiarize myself with Ryu and appreciate any pointers to resolve this issue. Thanks!

[image: Error after importing oslo]

Comment: That didn't change anything in the error message.

Comment: Believe it or not, it didn't!

Comment: @PeterWood I have added the screenshot of the error and it is what I said it is.

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt-get install python-oslo.config`? Were there any errors whilst installing?

Comment: `sudo pip install oslo.config --upgrade`

Comment: Thanks, the last one worked!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to easy install ryu application, Try [sdnds-tw/ryuinstaller](https://github.com/sdnds-tw/ryuInstallHelper). It's work for me.

Answer (score 1):

## Try this, It worked like wonder for me:

pip install 'oslo.config<2.0.0'

Comment: this helped.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are running your application in python 2.7.

Please make sure you don't have any old version of python come wit linux distro. 
Please read my another post and see if ot can help.
[no module named numpy python2.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34915812/no-module-named-numpy-python2-7/34915934#34915934)